# How to mock out a response triggered by a function on the same component in a wrapper?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

My component has a function which is triggered when a save button is clicked. Then based on that a fetch is done in the wrapper and the fetch response is then again passed down as a prop. So the putFn property accepts a function, the putResponse accepts a Promise.

I would like to mock the wrapper and focus in this test just on the component, in this example "myComponent".

Given the following test setup:

**./MyComponent.test.js**

```
function setup() {
  let mockPutResponse;
  const putMockFn = jest.fn(() => {
    mockPutResponse = Promise.resolve(
      JSON.stringify({ success: true, loading: false })
    );
  });
  render(<MyComponent putFn={putMockFn} putResponse={mockPutResponse} />);
  return { putMockFn };
}

test("MyComponent saves the stuff", async () => {
  const { putMockFn } = setup();

  const button = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /save changes/i });
  userEvent.click(button);

  // this passes
  expect(putMockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();

  // this does not pass since the component shows this message
  // based on the putResponse property
  expect(await screen.findByText(/saved successfully/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

How can I mock the return value passed into the **putResponse** property?

The component I want to test is something in the line of this:

**./MyComponent.js**

```
import React from "react";

const MyComponent = ({ putFn, putResponse }) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={putFn}>
      {putResponse?.loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
      {putResponse?.success && <p>saved succesfully</p>}
      <label htmlFor="myInput">My input</label>
      <input name="myInput" id="myInput" type="text" />
      <button>Save changes</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Which is used by a kind of wrapper, something similar to:

**./App.js** (arbitrary code)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";

export default function App() {
  const [wrapperPutResponse, setWrapperPutResponse] = useState();
  const handlePut = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setWrapperPutResponse({ loading: true });
    // timeout, in the actual app this is a fetch
    setTimeout(function() {
      setWrapperPutResponse({ success: true, loading: false });
    }, 3000);
  };

  return <MyComponent putFn={handlePut} putResponse={wrapperPutResponse} />;
}
```

Created a sandbox: codesandbox.io/s/bold-cloud-2ule8?file=/src/MyComponent.test.js

Comment: Please, provide the code you're testing. It remains unclear how putFn and putResponse are supposed to work together.

Comment: @EstusFlask Sure, created a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-cloud-2ule8?file=/src/MyComponent.test.js

Comment: Consider adding the component to the question since it's relevant. I don't see why `expect(putMockFn).toHaveBeenCalled()` would pass in one case but not another. But it appears that putFn and putResponse are unrelated. The component is stateless, so these props should be tested independently. Also, making mockPutResponse a promise is a mistake, it's expected to be plain object. I expect it to be something like https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-dan-5qb52?file=/src/MyComponent.test.js .

Comment: That's the question indeed. They are related in the sense of that when the putMockFn is called, that will do a fetch. Once the wrapper component (in this example App.js) is done with that fetch it will return the mockPutResponse. That's where I'm having trouble mocking.

Comment: This is how it's used in App but this isn't presumed by MyComponent, where putFn and putResponse are unrelated. For unit test, I'd suggest to stick to the approach I mentioned. If you're worried how MyComponent works with existing component like App in a scenario you described, consider doing integration test with both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Wrapper` component to render and control `MyComponent`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { screen, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";


const mockPutResponse = jest.fn()

function setup() {

  const Wrapper = () => {
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)
    const response = clicked ? { success: true, loading: false} : null
    useEffect(() => {
      mockPutResponse.mockImplementation(() => {
        setClicked(true)
      })
    }, [])
    return <MyComponent putFn={mockPutResponse} putResponse={response} />
  }

  render(<Wrapper />);
}

test("MyComponent saves the stuff", async () => {
  setup()
  // expect(await screen.findByText(/loading.../i)).toBeInTheDocument();

  const button = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /save changes/i });
  userEvent.click(button);

  // this passes
  expect(mockPutResponse).toHaveBeenCalled();

  // had some issue with expect acting up when using the toBeInDocument assertion 
  // so I used this one instead
  const text = await screen.findByText(/saved succesfully/i)
  expect(text).toBeTruthy()
});
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-perlman-0n1h5?file=/src/MyComponent.test.js:0-1132)

Comment: This works. Kind of a bummer to have to create a Wrapper component just for the handling of that mockPutRespose. But I guess it's the only way to be able to handle te conditional setting for when the response should either be null or the respose. Thanks!

Comment: I would actually not use the wrapper but rather test on prop independently in different tests

Comment: Leaving the click handling for wat it is and just assert on the setting of the prop?

Comment: the click should just call the form's `onSubmit` which you are already covering by testing that `mockPutResponse` has been called